# Rapidly Displaying Images from Raspberry Pi Camera onto tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to create a "stream" from the Raspberry Pi camera and display it onto a tkinter canvas. To do so, I am currently capturing an image, saving the image, loading the image into tkinter, and displaying the image onto the canvas. Is there any way to do this without the saving and loading portion? Note: I have to use the canvas because I am using its geometry drawing features to draw circles and lines on top of the loaded image. Here is my current code:

```
camera.capture(self.liveStreamName, resize = (485,485))
self.C.delete(self.canvasImage)
self.DisplayImg = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = self.liveStreamName)
self.C.create_image(242.5,242.5,image = self.DisplayImg)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read docs.

-

Tkinter can use `PIL/pillow` module which has functions `fromstring`, `frombuffer`, `frombytes` to create Image from data in memory.

Pillow: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#functions

Tkinter: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

-

Capture: http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.capture

In place of filename you can use file-like object. Maybe you could use `StringIO` or `ByteIO` module (`IO` in Python 3) to create file-like object in memory and use it with `frombuffer`.

But maybe camera has functions like `to_string`, `to_array`, `to_buffer` and you could use it with `fromstring`, `fromarray` or `frombuffer` without `StringIO`.

-

See picamera.array: http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_array.html

-

so now ... read docs ;) Good luck.